# How to remove duplicate directory from url in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, joomla

I have URLs like this:

```
domain.com/gedenkportal
domain.com/gedenkportal/gedenkportal
domain.com/gedenkportal/gedenkportal/schiermeyer-heinrich
```

and I would like to shorten them to:

```
error 404 / don't allow access to that file
domain.com/gedenkportal
domain.com/gedenkportal/schiermeyer-heinrich
```

I don't want anyone to be able to access the old "/gedenkportal" directory (before the redirect)

My current code is:

```
RewriteRule ^gedenkportal(/.+)$ /$1 [R=302,L,NC]
```

But that one doesn't work at all. Can anyone please help me out on this? :-)

Comment: Could you please confirm if you are hitting `domain.com/gedenkportal/gedenkportal/schiermeyer-heinrich` url in browser and you want it to redirect it on browser to `domain.com/gedenkportal`?

Comment: My full htaccess is just the default joomla htaccess file. @anubhava

Comment: I want to hit /gedenkportal in the browser and it should also display that in the url address bar, but actually retrieve the content from /gedenkportal/gedenkportal.

I also want to hit /gedenkportal/schiermeyer-heinrich in the browser and it should also display that in the url address bar, but actually retrieve the content from /gedenkportal/gedenkportal/schiermeyer-heinrich. @RavinderSingh13

Comment: @Felix if you are doing Joomla development, please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.